# How to train neural network for text-to-speech task?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

I have 12000 audio files which lengths is about 2 seconds and 12000 text files with phonemes and time stamps for audio files. My task is to train NN to synthesize audio for train data set only. I already tried feedforward NN and it works good only for 20 audio files. Which architecture should i choose? What should i do with data(preprocessing e.t.c)?